# $5.30$ converted to a fraction or mixed number in lowest terms

Tags: fractions

$5.30$ converted to a fraction or mixed number in lowest terms

The correct answer they got on my worksheet is $5 \frac3{50}$, but I get $5 \frac{15}{50}$.

Comment: Since $$\frac{3}{50} = \frac{3}{50} \cdot \frac{2}{2} = \frac{6}{100} = 0.06$$ the answer key is incorrect since $$5\frac{3}{50} = 5 + \frac{3}{50} = 5 + \frac{6}{100} = 5.06$$ Your answer is not in simplest form since $$\frac{15}{50} = \frac{3 \cdot 5}{10 \cdot 5} = \frac{3}{10}$$ so your answer reduces to $5\frac{3}{10}$.

Answer (score 2):

$5.30 = 5 + 0.30$

$0.30 = \frac{30}{100} = \frac 3 {10}$

Therefore $5.30 = 5 \frac 3{10}$ in "mixed number" form, but that's bad notation (it could be confused for $5 \cdot \frac 3{10}$). You could also write it as $5+\frac 3{10}$.

But it'd be best to just reduce it to a fraction:

$5 = \frac 5 1  = \frac{50}{10}$

Therefore $5.30 = 5 + 0.30 = \frac{50}{10} + \frac{3}{10} = \frac{53}{10}$